# Checklist items for Android-GO

Tags: android, android-go

What is checklist for android GO? I want to update my android app for android GO operating System. how to check my App is compatible Android GO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the requirements to be Android go ready below

1. Runs on device with **512MB RAM**
2. APK installed size **≤ 40MB**
3. **Target SDK 26 (Oreo)**
4. App **starts ≤ 5s** (connected to WiFi)
5. **RAM ≤ 50MB PSS**

What is **PSS**?

The "proportional set size" (PSS) of a process is the count of pages it has in memory, where each page is divided by the number of processes sharing it. 
So if a process has 1000 pages all to itself, and 1000 shared with one other process, its PSS will be 1500.

Checkout more details at official android developer site here [Optimize for devices running Android (Go edition)](https://developer.android.com/develop/quality-guidelines/building-for-billions-device-capacity.html#androidgo)

Answer (score 1):

Checklist items for Android (Go edition):

1. targetSdkVersion ≥ API 26
2. The app should run smoothly on devices with ≤ 1GB RAM.
3. App size ≤ 40MB
4. App startup time ≤ 5 seconds
5. The Proportional Set Size (PSS) of the app's RAM usage ≤ 50MB,  For games, the PSS of the game's RAM usage ≤ 150

You can use the Multiple APK feature on the Play Console to distribute a specific APK for Android (Go edition) devices but you should only do so without compromising the experience (e.g. you should avoid removing features).

The APK targeting Android (Go edition) devices needs to declare `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.ram.low" android:required="true">`, target at least API Level 26, and have a higher version code than the non-Go edition APK.

Checkout more details at official android developer site here [Optimize for devices running Android (Go edition)](https://developer.android.com/develop/quality-guidelines/building-for-billions-device-capacity.html#androidgo)

Comment: If someone has already installed the app on Android Go devices what happens if I exclude it in Google Play? Will they still get updates or will their app get uninstalled?

Comment: I am not sure but I think they can't update app but existing app will remain in their device.